# laravel get request to model in protected variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to send request in function controller to protected variable my model

My controller. send `$request->NAME;` to My model

```
   class InfoController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
           //send $request->NAME to My model
        }
    }
```

My model. Get request from controller `$request->NAME;`

```
class Info extends Model
{
    protected $table = $request->NAME'.BND_ST_INFO'; //Get request from controller
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['ID','INFO_NAME'];
}
```

Comment: You could make a public function to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the setTable() method in the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

```
app(Info::class)->setTable($request->NAME'.BND_ST_INFO');
```